# Is there an specific way to treat error in loop python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spotify

I found a notebook, but I stucked at this point In[10]:

```
import pandas as pd
```

loop through track URIs and pull artist URI using the API,
then use artist URI to pull genres associated with that artist
store all these in a dictionary

```
     for t_uri in track_uris:
    
        dict_genre[t_uri] = {'artist_uri': "", "genres":[]}
    
        r = requests.get(BASE_URL + 'tracks/' + t_uri, headers=headers)
        r = r.json()
        a_uri = r['artists'][0]['uri'].split(':')[2]
        dict_genre[t_uri]['artist_uri'] = a_uri
    
        s = requests.get(BASE_URL + 'artists/' + a_uri, headers=headers)
        s = s.json()
        dict_genre[t_uri]['genres'] = s['genres']
```

```
KeyError                                  
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-43-3c5b75bf03e3> in <module>()
    14     r = requests.get(BASE_URL + 'tracks/' + t_uri, headers=headers)
    15     r = r.json()    
---> 16     a_uri = r['artists'][0]['uri'].split(':')[2]*    
KeyError: 'artists'
```

Source:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-spotify-data-with-python-tableau-687f2f528cdd
- https://jovian.ai/abode118/spotify-data-prep

Comment: Try `print(r)` there to see what the data contains.

Comment: print(r) inside for
`output: {'error': {'status': 429, 'message': 'API rate limit exceeded'}}
`
print(r) outside for
`output: {'error': {'status': 429, 'message': 'API rate limit exceeded'}}
{'album': {'album_type': 'single', 'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': *URL Links after this*
`

Comment: "rate limit exceeded" seems like the obvious problem.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I really appreciate your assist

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-an-artist), if you are not getting the response with the `artists` key, there are these options:

- 401 error. Bad or expired token. This can happen if the user revoked a token or the access token has expired. You should re-authenticate the user.
- 403 error. Bad OAuth request (wrong consumer key, bad nonce, expired timestamp...). Unfortunately, re-authenticating the user won't help here.
- [Very unlikely for you] 429 error. The app has exceeded its rate limits.

Otherwise, you wouldn't have this error. So check your `header`, it contains an incorrect token.